# is $ \arg\min_{x} \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + f(x)\\ $ defined everywhere?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\overline {\mathbb{R}}$.
We make the following definitions:

$$
g(y)=\arg\min_{x} \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + f(x)
$$

$f(x)  \text{is convex}, t \ge 0$

I want to show that g(y) is always defined which means that $  \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + f(x)$  always has a unique minimum no matter what convex function $f(x)$ I choose. I know that $  \frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + f(x)$ is strictly convex but strictly convex function may not have a minimum. If it has a minimum then it is a global minimum.
Can I somehow utilize the fact that $\|x-y\|^2 $ has a global minimum to show that  $\frac{1}{2t}\|x-y\|^2 + f(x)$ has a global minimum ? If it is not true I'm looking for a counter example.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant fact here is that convex functions are bounded below by linear functions. Assuming f is [proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_convex_function) convex then there is a point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a vector $g\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x) \geq g\cdot (x -x_0)+ f(x_0)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. So in particular we have

$\frac{1}{2t} \lVert x-y\rVert^2 + f(x) \geq \frac{1}{2t} \lVert x-y\rVert^2 + g\cdot (x -x_0)+ f(x_0)$,

and the later lower bound always has a finite minimum.

Comment: I understand that the function of interest is convex and is bounded from below by another convex function (the right side of the inequity) that has a minimum. How can you conclude from that that the function of interest (on the left side) has a finite minimum ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample:
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for } x \in (0,1), \\ 0 & \text{else}.\end{cases}$$
Then, for $t = 1$ and $y = 2$, the infimal value of $x \mapsto \frac12 \|x - y\|^2 - f(x)$ is $1/2$, but this infimal value is not attained.

Note that this $f$ is not lower semicontinuous, which is required for the existence of a minimizer.